# Verify if image is original or xerox

Tags: image-processing, python-tesseract

I am writing a python application to do kyc of a customer, I want to verify whether  the document like passport shared by customer is original or a photo copy, how can we verify that using python image processing lib pytesseract?

Or do we need to use any other lib or any other algorithm you could help me with please.

Comment: You can't. Full stop.

Comment: Is it possible to some extent if not 100%

Comment: Mh, maybe 1%, with a low quality xerox and a good quality camera ?